# Orm Code Generator On Runtime

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using Visual Studio and fluent Nhibernate.
There is some designer,code generator for generate code.(LLBGEN,DEVART ENTITY DEVELOPER ets..)
but I wanna generate code on runtime.Is there any product for genereate fluent nhibernate code
on runtime?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Why would you want to code-gen that?

Comment: @Phill I wanna make flexible application.I dont wanna build project all changes.I will save generated code to a table on the database and if I add new column or new table I dont have to build project.

Comment: Sounds like you shouldn't be using an ORM at all.

Answer (score 0):

I dont now if there's anything specifically for Nhibernate, but you can generate and compile code on runtime in .net with Roslyn.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx

You would need to script it so you have the usual Nhibernate tools output their generated code, then you use Roslyn to compile it on the fly.

Comment: I am using Roslyn its perfect but I need to generator.